Find Lipschitz constant for an absolute function
My fellow mates,
I am trying to check if a function has bounded gradients and find its Lipschitz constant if the following is true:
|df(z)/dx - df(y)/dy| <= L |z-y|
Using functions like f(z) = z^2 - 10, I can get the above equation in a form where finding the Lipschitz constant becomes extremely easy:
|df(z)/dz - df(y)/dy| = |2z - 2y| = 2|z - y|, thus L = 2
But how can I find it for an absolute function like:
f(z) = |z-10|
Here, the derivatives that I get is:
f'(z) = 1 (for z>10)
f'(z) = -1 (for z<10)
f'(z) = 0 (let's just assume it)

How do I go from here to find the Lipschitz constant?
Please help.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
